# Meaning of phrase in a journal

Tags: meaning

I'm reading a journal but didn't get the meaning of following sentence:

> **Conflict prediction
> is based on aircraft trajectory prediction *and is less certain the farther* in
> advance the prediction, however.**

That phrase 'less certain the farther' makes this sentence hard to understand.
Please explain the meaning of this sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"less certain the farther" is not really a phrase here. A number of words have been omitted, and the second part of the sentence should be interpreted *and (the conflict prediction) is less certain the further in advance the (aircraft trajectory) prediction (is), however*. Another paraphrase would be *and the farther in advance the aircraft trajectory prediction is, the less certain the conflict prediction is.*

The sentence refers to two predictions, and it is not totally clear which prediction is meant by the second-last word. While I believe that explicitly using the word "prediction" here implies that it is not the same prediction as mentioned immediately prior, it is possible that the paraphrase should be *and the conflict prediction is less certain the further in advance it is.*